# IE9 / IE10 slightly larger font sizes?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-10

Black is firefox, light blue /azure is chrome (barely noticable against firefox), and the dark purple is IE10.

Their font sizes (11px) and font-family (Helvetica) are all exactly the same, however you will notice how much larger IE10 renders its font.

It also seems to apply very heavy anti-aliasing to each character.

I know part of the 'challenge' is creating a site that will work across multiple browsers, but has anyone got any solutions that could correct IE10's increased font size?

[image: Overlaid]

Comment: do you use a css reset?

Comment: Every browser has a different way of rendering text.  That's just the way it is.

Comment: as far as I remember IE doesn't handle odd vlaues like `11px and 13px etc` and percentage values accurately like the rest of the browsers. Can you verify if you set the `font-size` to `12px` instead and see if there are any differemce?

Comment: @NicholasKing Yep, I am already using a css reset  (YUI 3.4.1)

Comment: Are you sure they are using the correct font and have you supplied a fallback font for helvetica?  Most machines don't come installed with helvetica as you have to pay for it

Comment: What does the IE developer toolbar and chrome developer tools think is being rendered out (font sizes etc.)

Comment: Could this be because IE10 does not adhere to sub-pixel font anti-aliasing?

Comment: @Pete Helvetica _is_ a web-safe font, and all images were taken from the same machine.

Comment: It is a web safe font but not all machines have it installed and so it won't render - for example my machine wouldn't use helvetica as I don't have it installed on my machine

Comment: Helvetica is not a core font except on Mac OS X or iOS, so it isn’t web safe by that definition. IE substitutes arial for helvetica though, if you just specify helvetica in your font stack without a fallback.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem, in IE some parts on my page were broken.
I changed the font-size unit from px to pt, but you have to recalculate the values(divide the px value by approx. 1.36367, 15/11 exactly). 
Now the font is rendered with the same size in IE8-10 and FF, no broken parts.

Comment: According to [the CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-values/#absolute-lengths), the pt/px ratio is exactly 4/3, or 1.33333... But there may be rounding errors in browsers.

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn Thanks. I didin't look at the CSS specs. I adjusted the pt value until I got the result I wanted. But I will try spec Ratio.

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn I tried it out with 4/3, but i must say 15/11 fits better for me.

Answer (score 0):

IE9+ [uses sub-pixel rendering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh237264%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for fonts, and it results in slightly different size of text boxes (sometimes with non-integer pixel size) compared to other browsers. But here the problem seems to be more in `line-height` value, which probably is default (based on the font itself) and results in different values in different browsers because of rounding. Setting the explicit `line-height` value in pixels should minimize the difference.